# Parent Controllers data clears when navigate between child states: AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I've 4 states as shown below

```
$stateProvider.state('search', {
            url: '/search',
            controller: 'ControllerA',
            template: TemplateA
        }).state('results', {
            url: '/searchResult/:queryString',
            controller: 'ControllerA',
            template: TemplateA
        }).state('search.child1', {
            controller: 'ControllerChild1',
            template: TemplateChild1
        }).state('search.child2', {
            url: '/child2',
            controller: 'ControllerChild2',
            template: TemplateChild2
        });

.controller('ControllerA' function() {
   this.selectedItem = '';
});
```

**Summary about my states:**
Both 'search' and 'result' states uses same controller and html. 'search.child1' and 'search.child2' are 2 child states of search(They are tab inside search page). When user launches application by default search.child1 is selected.

**Problem statement:**

1. When user search for some item 'selectedItem' will updated one of
   the scope variable in ControllerA (inside 'search' contoller).
2. When user move from state 'search.child1' to 'search.child2' selectedItem
   will become undefined which is there in parent state.

I don't understand why it is happening here, when i move between child states why parent variables are cleared? How to prevent it from happening?

I tried following things

```
this.$state.go('search.child2', {}, { reload: 'search.child2' });

this.$state.transitionTo('search.child2', {}, { notify: false });
```